# Disable DropDownList until other DropDown not get value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have few drop down list(for example i say ddl1,ddl2,ddl3)) where first row is always empty string, what i trying to do is when in ddl1 is empty string selected i disabled ddl2 and ddl3,when i choise ddl1 value than i enabled ddl2 , and when i choise value for ddl2 i enable ddl3 etc, on the end if i again set empty string to ddl1 i disabled ddl2 and ddl3...etc

I try to do this on change:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#ddl1").change(function () {
   if ($("#ddl1").val() == 0) {
     $('#ddl2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#ddl3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
       $('#ddl2').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
});
```

This work good, but problem is that `.change(function ())` required to first change value of ddl to run code, how I can run this on app start, or component create, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
$("#ddl1").change(function () {
   if ($("#ddl1").val() == 0) {
     $('#ddl2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#ddl3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
       $('#ddl2').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
}).trigger("change");
```

Note the `trigger("change")` at the end.

Comment: Its very simple but effective solution, its works like charm.. Thanx